# ¿Como puedo hacer para que un input de tipo number acepte números decimales?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Estoy trabajando en un catalogo contable y necesito que una serie de input me permitan aceptar números decimales.
Lo tengo de esta manera:

```html
<input id="Descuadre" class="form-control text-right" type="number" min="0" step="0.05" />
```

se supone que todo esta en el step pero igual no me permite ingresar números decimales, también probé con any en el step y nada.
Esto a muchos de ustedes les funciona, he incluso si lo ejecutan también funciona, pero por alguna manera a mi no me esta funcionando.
¿Que estoy haciendo mal? o ¿Como puedo solucionar esto?

Comment: Disculpa que responda, aun no puedo añadir comentarios. ¿Integraste el atributo como igual a?
```
step="0.05"
```

Comment: Te falta el simbolo de igual = en step

Comment: @JheymanMejia Gracias por corregirme, fue error mio al formular la pregunta, ya la edite.

Comment: No entiendo qué es lo que no funciona. En este [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cyku18e9/) funciona correctamente. Posiblemente es necesario indicar con qué datos estás probando

Comment: @Alfabravo si, es lo que yo no entiendo tampoco, pruebo con numeros como 1000.00 y no me toma el punto

Comment: No entiendo *lo que estás preguntando*. No entiendo por qué dices que no te deja ingresar decimales, pues en la prueba que puse en el enlace sí lo permite y el step es de .05 como lo definiste.

Comment: @Alfabravo estoy trabajando con un template en proyecto web con asp.net mvc, crees que sea cosas del tema?

Comment: @Alfabravo si, se que funciona pero por alguna manera no me esta funcionando como debe.

Comment: Yo creo que algo en lo que pones alrededor está haciendo override a lo que defines para el campo. Tal vez añadiendo más detalles al código en tu pregunta podamos entender mejor

Comment: @DeybiTaboraPaz creo que el problema podría ser de localización si tienes configurados los locales en español tu equipo espera coma en lugar de punto. Por esa razón aquí lo vemos funcionar y no ocurre lo mismo allá.

Comment: @quevedo ya lo solucione, el problema era el tema que estoy usando, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con un poco de JavaScript si te sirve :

```html
<input type="number"  required name="price" onkeyup="/^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/.test(this.value)?'inherit':this.value=''">
```

En este ejemplo solo acepta dos decimales si deseas mas modifica la expresión regular y pon el numero que desees donde esta el numero 2

Comment: Justo lo que yo buscaba, gracias!!

Answer (score 0):

El codigo que has puesto funciona tal cual, pero con decimales que cumplen el step que has proporcionado (numeros de 0.05 en 0.05), es decir, un 0.01 no funciona, pero si un 0.05 o 0.10 y asi sucesivamente, si quieres que funcionen TODOS los decimales, prueba a poner un step de 0.01 y deberia funcionar.

Saludos.